# How to make the <main> background-color transparent but not the elements inside it?

Tags: html, css

I have a  element with a lot of other elements in it like headings, images,videos etc. I'm trying to make the background-color of the  to a transparent antique white (using the opacity property), but then the images and videos inside the  become transparent as well.
How do I bypass that reaction?

Comment: See here how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
body{
  color:black;
}
body::after {
  content: "";
  background: url('image') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size:     cover;        
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```